# How to remove combo1 data value based on second combo data value

Tags: javascript

I have two combo first.if i m choose second combo in particular value based on the second combo value it ll remove first combo specific value.
what is the code for this

Comment: `Abracadabra --comboboxes`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cu8KK/3/ update code i have selected first combo value and that value is remove from second combo

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/cu8KK/3/ 
Hii

Please check above fiddle code for your requirement

```
<select id="first">
<option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
</select>

<select id="second">
<option value=1>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
 <option>3</option>
 <option>4</option>
</select>
```

jquery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#first").change(function(){
alert("change");
    alert($(this).val());
    $("#second option[value="+$(this).val()+"]").remove();

});
});
```